# Apache keeps returning 500

Tags: .htaccess, apache-2.4

(Im working with Apache/2.4.10 on Windows 7 (64 Bit) )

I have a directory "test" in my document root with several files on my local apache:

```
test
|____.htaccess
|____.htpasswd
|____admin.php
|____install.php
|____crypt.php
|____index.php
```

My .htaccess looks as follows ...

```
<Files ~ "^(admin|install|crypt.php)\.php$">
 AuthType basic
 AuthName "Administration-Script"
 AuthUserFile .htpasswd
 Require user siteadmin
</Files>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
 RewriteRule .? - [L]
 RewriteRule .? index\.php
</IfModule>
```

... and my .htpasswd as follows

```
siteadmin:$1$JHmM5O1B$4tXjIlyFNdQGWzggoPL2E/
```

When I open localhost/test/admin.php I keep getting a 500 error and i can't see why. I think the problem lays within the <Files>-Tag. The basic auth config seems to be wrong because when I just remove the lines inside the <Files>-Tag everything works just fine.

I googled a bit but found nothing which would bring me closer to a solution.

Can someone please tell were i made a mistake?

Comment: What is Apache's error_log telling you?

Answer (score 0):

Looking it up in the err log was the essential hint. It told me the .htpasswd file could not be found. I now typed in the full path to the htpasswd file and now it works.